# Changing the font of the *title* in flexdashboard Rmd file?

Tags: css, r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to add custom css using a custom local font for flexdashboard but I can't for the life of me figure out how to change the title font, not the chart title, or the body, but the title itself. And by title I mean this is the header:

```
title: "Themed dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: custom.css
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `custom.css` define a CSS rule like this:

```
.navbar-brand {
  font-family:  serif;
}
```